# Sending XML data from Java server to web app

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, server

I have a Java server that runs some processes on several nodes and stores data in XML files. The server is up and running and works as expected.

I need to build a web app that will display some of the information stored in the XML files that are handled by the server. The web app will most likely use Django, but I am happy to use a different framework, if it makes more sense in terms of handling the communication with a Java server.

My question is, how do I make a Java server send XML data to a web client, or send a request from the web client to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can construct wep app in django o java o php o .net webapi in rest with this xml for this tras with java client in other server 
With examples...
Server: Jax rs with xml
Other server: Unirest client